# For values in a matrix get value out of a vector and replace the matrix values

Tags: r, matrix

Ok complicated title, but actually it's quite easy to explain :-)

I have a Matrix M:

```
M<-matrix(c(1,3,4,5,7,6,2, 2,5,1,3,4,7,6, 1,7,3,2,5,4,6),nrow=3,ncol=7, byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    3    4    5    NA    6    2
[2,]    2    5    1    3    4    7    6
[3,]    1    7    3    2    5    4    NA
```

And I have a vector with weights W:

```
W<-c(0.4,0.2,0.15,0.1,0.07,0.05,0.02)
```

Now I want to replace all values in the matrix depending on the number in the matrix, with the value in the vector at this respective position. So my resulting Matrix (it needs to be a matrix) should look like this:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]  0.4  0.15 0.1   0.07  NA  0.05  0.2
[2,]  0.2  0.07 0.4   0.15  0.1   0.02  0.05
[3,]  0.4  0.02 0.15  0.2   0.07  0.1   NA
```

But I don't know how to achieve this.

```
M2<-W[M]
```

didn't achieve the desired results..any advice?

Comment: If you want to replace: `M[] <- W[M]`

Comment: Works very nice, thanks. And if you want to copy that to a new matrix without overwriting the old one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matrix(W[M], nrow=nrow(M))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]  0.4 0.15 0.10 0.07   NA 0.05 0.20
[2,]  0.2 0.07 0.40 0.15 0.10 0.02 0.05
[3,]  0.4 0.02 0.15 0.20 0.07 0.10   NA
```

Comment: What I forgot to mention is, that I sometimes have NA columns which should stay NA, that's why it's not working..I've edited my example.

Comment: Are you sure? My example works regardless of the NA presence. Double-check that your NA is not character "NA".